# How to check if SQLite query (insert, delete or update) is successful?

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, offline-caching

I am implementing Offline handling for an app. I will be saving the details from API to the local SQLite DB on a mobile device. I want to ensure that Offline handling works only if all the data from web service is inserted successfully in the DB. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: return back received msg ID's as a delivery in success insertation to server. and in server, design a mechanism to handle losted msg,s.

Comment: What about update and delete ?

Comment: do same for any msg. the msg meant any data that you are recieving in client. it can be delete, edit,......

Comment: Okay will check it. Thanks